# PBFT Consensus Algorithm

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, consensus

I still have some difficulties to understand how does the PBFT Consensus Algorithm work in Hyperledger Fabric 0.6. Are there any paper which describes the PBFT Algorithm in blockchain environment?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Have you ever read Pbft algorithm paper published in 2003?

Answer (score 2):

While Hyperledger Fabric v0.6 has been deprecated for quite some time (we are working towards release of v1.1 shortly, as I write this) we have preserved the archived repository, and the [protocol specification](https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md) contains all that you might want to know about how the system works.

It is really too long a description to add here.

Answer (score 0):

> Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance (PBFT)  is a protocol developed to
> provide consensus in the presence of Byzantine faults.
>
> The PBFT algorithm has three phases. These phases run in a sequence to
> achieve consensus: `pre-prepare`, `prepare`, and `commit`
>
> The protocol runs in rounds where, in each round, an elected leader
> node, called the `primary node`, handles the communication with the
> client. In each round, the protocol progresses through the three
> previously mentioned phases. The participants in the PBFT protocol are
> called `replicas`, where one of the replicas becomes primary as a
> leader in each round, and the rest of the nodes act as backups.
>
> ### Pre-prepare:
>
> This is the first phase in the protocol, where the primary node, or
> primary, receives a request from the client. The primary node assigns
> a sequence number to the request. It then sends the pre-prepare
> message with the request to all backup replicas. When the pre-prepare
> message is received by the backup replicas, it checks a number of
> things to ensure the validity of the message:
>
> - First, whether the digital signature is valid.
> - After this, whether the current view number is valid.
> - Then, that the sequence number of the operation's request message is valid.
> - Finally, if the digest/hash of the operation's request message is valid.
>
> If all of these elements are valid, then the backup replica accepts
> the message. After accepting the message, it updates its local state
> and progresses toward the preparation phase.
>
> ### Prepare:
>
> A prepare message is sent by each backup to all other replicas in the
> system. Each backup waits for at least 2F + 1 (F is the number of
> faulty nodes.) to prepare messages to be received from other replicas.
> They also check whether the prepared message contains the same view
> number, sequence number, and message digest values. If all these
> checks pass, then the replica updates its local state and progresses
> toward the commit phase.
>
> ### Commit:
>
> Each replica sends a commit message to all other replicas in the
> network. The same as the prepare phase, replicas wait for 2F + 1
> commit messages to arrive from other replicas. The replicas also check
> the view number, sequence number, and message digest values. If they
> are valid for 2F+ 1 commit messages received from other replicas, then
> the replica executes the request, produces a result, and finally,
> updates its state to reflect a commit. If there are already some
> messages queued up, the replica will execute those requests first
> before processing the latest sequence numbers. Finally, the replica
> sends the result to the client in a reply message. The client accepts
> the result only after receiving 2F+ 1 reply messages containing the
> same result.

[Reference](https://www.packtpub.com/product/mastering-blockchain-third-edition/9781839213199)